# bash compound if statement with booleans

Tags: bash, if-statement, boolean-operations

I am trying to figure out why bash "miss-behaves":

```
REG=true 
VIN=false

if $REG -a $VIN; then
    echo $REG $VIN
fi
```

when run, it yields:

```
$ bash test.sh 
true false
```

I was expecting nothing, can you show how to make a complete evaluation of both variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&&` instead in the most POSIX way:

```
if [[ "$REG" && "$VIN" ]]; then
    echo $REG $VIN
fi
```

If you want to use the `-a`, then surround with brackets:

```
if [ "$REG" -a "$VIN" ]; then
```

```
if $REG && $VIN; then
```

Comment: thanks, I never saw that you can use `&&` without `[[`  or  `[`

Comment: It is always tricky. I recommend the read of pages like http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression

Comment: Neither `[[ "$REG" && "$VIN" ]]` nor `[ "$REG" -a "$VIN" ]`, because they both check the strings "$REG" and "$VIN" to see if they're nonblank -- that is, they consider "true" and "false" to both be true (nonblank).

Comment: Oh, I see @GordonDavisson. And does `if $REG && $VIN;` work then?

Comment: @fedorqui: Yes, `if $REG && $VIN;` works because it treats the two strings as commands; `true` is actually a command that always succeeds, `false` is a command that always fails, and the `&&` makes a compound command that succeeds only if both individual commands succeed. This is what you want.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the patience @GordonDavisson . I just updated my answer to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

In `REG=true`, 'true' is a string. When you do `$REG`, you're executing the *command* `true`.

`if $REG -a $VIN` means "run the command `true` with the option '-a' and argument '$VIN', which are ignored by true. So it's the same as if you had `if true`.

`if $REG && $VIN` causes 'true' and 'false' to be executed and their results 'and-ed', which yields false.

`if [ "$REG" -a "$VIN" ]` DOES NOT WORK (as defined here). This is the same as `if test "true" -a "false"`. Any non-null string is true, so this statement is true. Same goes for `if [[ "$REG" && "$VIN" ]]`

However:

```
if [[ `$REG` && `$VIN` ]] # works
```

does work because here you execute the commands true and false.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way for you would be:

```
if [[ $REG = 'true' && $VIN = 'true' ]]; then
    echo "$REG $VIN"
fi
```

This is the most correct and safe way (unlike executing your `$REG` and `$VIN` as other answers suggest). For example, what is going to happen if `$REG` variable is empty? Or what if it equals to something different than just `true` or `false`?

If you want boolean behavior in bash, then consider the fact that empty strings are falsy.

```
REG=1
if [[ $REG ]]; then
    echo '$REG is true!'
fi
```

or like that for multiple variables:

```
REG=1
VIN=''

if [[ $REG && $VIN ]]; then
    echo '$REG and $VIN are true!'
fi
if [[ $REG && ! $VIN ]]; then
    echo '$REG is true and $VIN is false!'
fi
```

So, if you want something to be `false`, then either leave it unset or use an empty string.